# ¿Ingreso por consola de una constante #define para operación de matrices en C++?

Tags: c++, funciones, matrices, dev-c++

Hace un par de semanas publiqué una pregunta sobre un algoritmo para la generación de cuadros mágicos aleatorios. Las respuestas que recibí allí me hicieron notar lo inocente que estaba siendo a la hora de abordar el problema.

Ahora ya he logrado crear un algoritmo que puede hacer cuadros mágicos de gran tamaño, pero me encuentro con un problema diferente. Debido a la manera en la que estructuré el programa, sólo es posible cambiar el orden (N) de los cuadros a generar desde el editor. Adjunto las primeras líneas del programa para que se hagan una idea.

Mi pregunta es: ¿existe una manera de definir N desde la consola, por ingreso del usuario? Se me ocurre, tal vez, escribir un programa donde se ingrese N y que ése llame a éste, asignando N desde allí, pero no sé si es posible o cómo hacerlo.

Espero puedan ayudarme con este inconveniente.

Agradezco su atención.

```
//-------------------------------Librerías--------------------------------------
#include <clocale>      //setlocale()
#include <iostream>     //cout <<
#include <cmath>        //tgamma()
#include <cstdlib>      //rand() srand()
#include <ctime>        //time()

//----------------------------Defino constantes---------------------------------
#define clear() printf("\033[H\033[J")  //limpia la pantalla.
#define N       4                       //Orden del cuadro mágico.

//---------------------------Prototipo Funciones--------------------------------
void crear(int puzzle[][N]);            //Crea una matriz aleatoria con números 1-N^2 con filas mágicas.
void format(int puzzle[][N]);           //Asigna 0 a todos los elementos de la matriz.
bool check(int temp, int puzzle[][N]);  //Revisa si un número determinado ya está.
void reorganizar(int puzzle[][N]);      //Reorganiza los elementos de la matriz para hacerla mágica.
bool nomagifil(int i, int puzzle[][N]); //Revisa si la fila i no suma el número mágico.
bool nomagicol(int j, int puzzle[][N]); //Revisa si la columna j no suma el número mágico.
bool nomagidiags(int puzzle[][N]);      //Revisa si las diagonales no suman el número mágico.
bool nomagi(int puzzle[][N]);           //Revisa si el cuadro no es mágico.
void mostrar(int puzzle[][N]);          //Imprime la matriz.
double inte_max(double outputs);        //Número máximo de veces a repetir una acción aleatoria. 

//-----------------------------------main---------------------------------------
using namespace std;                    //Evito escribir std:: cada vez que refiera una librería.

int main(){
    //Herramientas
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "spanish");       //Permite el uso de carácteres especiales.
    srand(time(NULL));                  //Genera una semilla para rand().
    //Bucle
    char respuesta='\0';
    do{
        clear();                                //Limpia la pantalla.
        //Presentación
        cout <<"¡Bienvenido!\nA continuación, un cuadro mágico de orden "<<N<<" cuyo número mágico es "<<N*(N*N+1)/2<<".\n"<<endl;
        //Decalarar variables
        int puzzle[N][N]={0};                   //crea una matriz de N*N.
        //Proceso
        crear(puzzle);                          //Crea el cuadro.
        //Impresión
        mostrar(puzzle);                        //Muestra el cuadro.
        //¿Repetir?
        do{
            cout <<endl<<"¿Desea crear otro cuadro? (s/n) ";
            cin >>respuesta;
            if(respuesta!='s'&respuesta!='n')   //Si respuesta no es 's' o 'n' da error y repite.
                cout<<"ERROR: El caracter ingresado no es correcto, inténtelo de nuevo.\n";
        }while(respuesta!='s'&respuesta!='n');
    }while(respuesta=='s');                     //Si respuesta es 's', repite el bucle.
    //Terminar
    cout <<endl<<"¡Gracias por usar este programa! Pulse una tecla para salir.";
    cin.get();
    cin.ignore();                               //Pausa la pantalla y limpia el buffer.
    return 0;                                   //Termina el programa.
}
```

Comment: Me extraña que no lo haya preguntado nadie: ¿¿ Porqué no usas una variable, al igual que haces para preguntar al usuario si `desea crear otro cuadro` ??

Comment: Porque acabo de empezar y sé usar sólo los arreglos nativos del lenguaje. En funciones, cuando utilizas arreglos multidimencionales, debes especificar el tamaño de todas las dimensiones después de la primera y no se aceptan variables. Creo que la solución va a ser utilizar otro tipo, como sugieren más abajo.

Answer (score 2):

El `#define` es una instruccion de preprocesador. Esta literalmente copia y pega. En tu caso donde tienes una `N` pega un `4`. Este es el primer paso de la compilacion, por lo que es imposible cambiarla mientras corres el programa.

En este caso, lastimosamente tendras que modificarlo para tomar el dato mientras corre.

Te adelanto la solucion a el proximo problema que te toparas, que va a ser darle el tamaño a los array de forma dinamica, y te propongo 2 ideas:

1. Lo preferible, si te dejan usar la STL, es que uses `std::vector`. Aunque no te dejen usar la STL, hechale un vistaso, es una de las herramientas mas poderosas de C++
2. El el codigo se me hace muy a estilo C, usando `NULL`, `rand`, etc, aunque existen alternativas en C++. Por lo que creo que puede ser que si vas a tener que darle un tamaño a los arrays en el runtime puede que te pidan que uses `malloc` y `free`. En este caso lo que te puedo recomendar es que lo hagas asi, y investigues lo que son los punteros inteligentes, y lo que es RAII. Asi te ahorraras muchos dolores de cabeza.

Answer (score 0):

Reflexionando un poco sobre sus respuestas me di cuenta de que todo el proceso trabaja a través de iteradores, por lo tanto, el tamaño de la matriz no influye realmente. Siendo así, la solución que encontré fue añadir N no como una constante, sino como un argumento para las funciones, de esa manera sí puedo hacer que el usuario lo ingrese desde el main y las funcionamiento de las funciones no cambia:

```
//----------------------------Defino constantes---------------------------------
#define MAX     30              //Orden máximo del cuadro mágico.

//---------------------------Prototipo Funciones--------------------------------
void crear(int N, int puzzle[][MAX]);            //Crea un cuadro mágico de órden N.
void format(int N, int puzzle[][MAX]);           //Asigna 0 a todos los elementos de la matriz.
bool check(int temp, int N, int puzzle[][MAX]);  //Revisa si un número determinado ya está.
void reorganizar(int N, int puzzle[][MAX]);      //Reorganiza los elementos de la matriz para hacerla mágica.
bool nomagifil(int i, int N, int puzzle[][MAX]); //Revisa si la fila i no suma el número mágico.
bool nomagicol(int j, int N, int puzzle[][MAX]); //Revisa si la columna j no suma el número mágico.
bool nomagidiags(int N, int puzzle[][MAX]);      //Revisa si las diagonales no suman el número mágico.
bool nomagi(int N, int puzzle[][MAX]);           //Revisa si el cuadro no es mágico.
void mostrar(int N, int puzzle[][MAX]);          //Imprime la matriz.
```

Gracias por sus respuestas, me ayudaron mucho.

Answer (score -1):

Si generas un fichero .exe y lo que pretendes es pasarle el parámetro cuando lo arrancas.
ejemplo:     cuadrados.exe 4

Creo que esto te vendrá bien.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) // or char** argv
```

Y leer esto mejor..
http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/DEN36Up4/